# CSS problem with visibilty

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

I have the following code:

```
var d = document.createElement("div");
d.id = "d_1";
d.style.backgroundImage = "url(img/lr.png");
d.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
d.style.width = "150px";
d.style.height = "25px";
d.style.position = "absolute";
d.style.left = "460px";
d.style.top = "385px";
d.style.visibility = "visible";
document.documentElement.appendChild(d);
```

and that div isn't show with Opera and Chrome but it's show with firefox!

What's wrong?

Comment: Javascript has a try catch clause if you want to detect errors

Comment: visibility is 'visible' by default. You don't need to set it. Press F-12 and open the debugger and inspect that element in the DOM.

Comment: Is this posted somewhere we can look?

Comment: Also, document.documentElement returns the document root (ie. <html>), appending children to which is a bit questionable. I would rather append the new element to document.body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax error.

```
d.style.backgroundImage = "url(img/lr.png");
```

Should be

```
d.style.backgroundImage = "url(img/lr.png)";
```

Comment: Then the problem must be somewhere else and beyond the javascript in your original post.

Answer (score 1):

Correct this line:

```
d.style.backgroundImage = "url(img/lr.png");
```

to

```
d.style.backgroundImage = "url(img/lr.png)";
```